# How to post to Facebook page as page itself

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a blog module. When the admin add a new blog post, a new post will be made in the facebook wall of a page(Let's call it `Mypage`). The code for it is:

```
$_accessKey = FB_ACCESS_KEY;
$_feedId = FB_FEED_ID;

$attachment =  array(
                    'access_token'  => $_accessKey,
                    'message'       =>  $postData['message'],
                    'name'          => $postData['name'],
                    'description'   => $postData['caption']
            );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_feedId.'/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

In the above code:

`FB_ACCESS_KEY` is the access token of the App from an user `Test`
`FB_FEED_ID` is the feed id of the page.

Now the posting to the `Mypage` is working, but the posts are coming as `Added by Test`.
How can I make the post as if it was made by the `Mypage` itself?
`Test` is an administrator of the page `Mypage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating as a Page should solve the issue for you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadn't noticed that documentation page. That did it. :)